# using where statement with a sequence of ids

Tags: php, mysql

In my table, I have a column that it has a set of users id. its name is `users_id`.
each id separated with a comma(`,`).

ex : `users_id` = '1,2,3,4,5';

if I passed `$id=1` to my function, how can I using `where` statement ?

```
function($id){
$sql = "select * from content_noti
        where  ??????"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a leading and a trailing `,` in the field value in DB.

e.g.

Change

`1,2,3,4,5`

to

```
,1,2,3,4,5,
```

So that every Id has leading and trailing comma `,`

Now, update the function body:

```
function($id){
  $sql = "select * from content_noti 
        where  users_id LIKE '%,$id,%'"
}
```

In this case you don't have any possibility of mistake as if you search user id `1` then you will get only `1` and not `11` or `111` or `1343`.

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2373/1)

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple ids than it would be better to use `IN` with query

```
$sql = "select * from content_noti where id IN  (?)"
```

if you are looking for reverse than use `find_in_set`

```
 $sql = "select * from content_noti where FIND_IN_SET(?, id)";
```

Comment: I think OP means in the field there is a string with the comma separated values for which he wants to match 1 value...

Comment: in that case he/she can use `find_in_set`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in mysql:

```
function($id){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM content_noti WHERE users_id REGEXP '(^|,)" . $i . "($|,)'";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * from content_noti where users_id = "1" OR users_id = LIKE '%1,%' OR users_id = LIKE '%,1%'
```

Storing multiple chunks of data as a single comma seperated colum is really poor design for databases and if at all possible you should look into normalizing this by making a coupling table and joining on that.

The performance of the above query will be terrible and it'll be hard to maintain.

Comment: Query opens up to errors; It would match id's `11`, `12`, `13`, and so on as well

Comment: Ah yeah. Well my point with "hard to maintain" exactly, I missed even more possible cases.